# Sqlite Android Raw Query INSERT INTO Not Working

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I wanna insert some row to a table in Android, I'm using this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Column_1, Column_1) VALUES ('X',100);
```

The query runs and no exception is thrown, but when I retrieve all rows from `MyTable`,  no row
is returned.

I do not want to use the `insert` method, because the queries are read from a file and I want to insert them to the database.

What's wrong with my code?

**Update** : The `rawQuery()` method doesn't run the query, but `execSQL()` does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The title of your question suggests you're using [`rawQuery()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29). It just compiles the SQL but does not run it. Calling one of the `moveTo...()` methods on the returned `Cursor` would also execute the SQL.

For an insert query, use [`execSQL()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) instead of `rawQuery()`, even if the documentation incorrectly states it should not be used with `INSERT`.

Comment: You're right. Often people think that queries and commands are synonyms.

Comment: Why `execSQL()` when you can use build-in `insert()` method?

Comment: @Ragnar OP doesn't want to use `insert()` and for a good reason.

Comment: @laalto yes i use `rawQuery()`,and there is no cursor, just run a query, is `SqliteDatabase` has submit method or something that run the query ?

Comment: @Ragnar I Want to insert 20000 data for my client, and for performance i wanna use this, i try the insert method but it take too long (about 2 hour) but the sql command in way faster

Comment: @laalto i will try `execSQL()` and see whats happen.

Comment: @JavadVovin It will work but won't solve your performance problem. Even though `insert()` introduces some overhead, it's really waiting for disk I/O that drives execution time.

Comment: @laalto the queries is written with `UNION` and each query contains 100 data, i think it's better this way.

Answer (score 0):

How is your Table organized? 
You seem to use twice the same column **Column_1** is this a typo?

Alternative, you could use insert-command of SQListeDatabase insteat:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29

Comment: **Column_1** is just an example, The Name of column is correct, and i cant use `insert` method because there is too much data.

Comment: I see - did the comment above helped you out? So far i read, that execSQL is not allowed for inserts ... Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE - but there are plenty of examples using it with Inserts though. rawQuery could work, but for me it seems you at least should check the return cursor.
Last idea: you should use 'value' for all your values e.g. ('X','100')